# Do you use links?

Tags: links

DO you use links in your wordpress and why? Isn't it much easier to use you browser's bookmarks? I don't get the idea of having links at all!

Please enlight me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Links are not supposed to be bookmarks, they are more of a convenient way to integrate links in site. The feature is kinda underused (I think blogrolls it single most common usage for it and seems to start to fade) and so under-appreciated.

Really there are plenty of stuff you can do with links, for example I wrote a [post how to use them to display banners](http://www.rarst.net/script/wordpress-links/).

Comment: I tried so hard... But I couldn't find the way to use links... As you said... The feature is underused and will fade away with time. . Is there anyone who actually uses links for something else